# Workaround for different origin JSON XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, rest, cross-domain

made a site that sends request to yahoo.com. it works locally but no on another machine. i have determined that the yahoo API is working fine, and a file is indeed fetched by yahoo's server.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&g=d&a=0&b=1&c=2012&ignore=.csv. 


Origin http://dl.dropbox.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: Could you please show the code that resulted in this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Yahoo! JSONP API instead.

Comment: @bouncingHippo - There are a *lot* of resources and questions about this if you'd take a second to look.